# Wrong character encoding JSON object response from AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I'm getting this html back from the ajax response

```
{"town_id":"41","town_name":"\u0391\u0393\u0393\u0395\u039b\u039f\u039a\u0391\u03a3\u03a4\u03a1\u039f"}
```

and my JSON object is this:

```
0   Object { town_id="41",  town_name="ΑΓΓΕΛΟΚΑΣΤΡΟ"}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: well this looks like the name of the town is called like this?!? :-) Your name sounds greece, are this no greece letters?

Comment: "I'm getting this html back" — That isn't HTML.

Comment: "Does anyone know how to fix this?" — What makes you think it is broken? What do you expect to get?

Comment: "Wrong character encoding" — The response appears to be ASCII, which is a subset of pretty much every character encoding. The second line of "code" you provide appears to use the correct letters for that data. (The encoding, since you aren't showing us raw bytes, is whatever Stackoverflow is using)

Comment: Quentin I was using Firebug and that was it was showing in the HTML tab. I was expecting to see tha same data as those on JSON object. Thus said, parsing the data with Jquery will I get the correct values(meaning those in JSON object)?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your php page:

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: I'm using Wordpress. Could you be more specific? Should I put it in index.php fro example?